# Upload video to PandaStream in android

Tags: out-of-memory, httpurlconnection, pandastream

I want to upload LARGE video files to pandastream. I was able to upload small video by streaming. But when large videos are uploaded, got out of memory exception due to internal buffering. So Inorder to overcome this issue i tried the following two ways:

**By using setFixedLengthStreamingMode()**
But i got the excetion as expected 234 bytes but recieved 384 bytes...

**By using setChunkedStreamingMode()**
Here while uploading large videos i got the exception as File not found.

Could any one please help me with a solution.